# Apache POI - CellStyles applied to cells on cloned sheet appear on original sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

In a program I'm writing, I prepare an excel sheet ("master") and clone it multiple times. Each time I clone this master sheet I apply `CellStyle`s to specific cells on the new cloned sheet. The problem is, every time I apply `CellStyle`s to the cells on the sheet(s) I clone, the styles kept appearing on the master sheet and all other cloned sheets. Here's the snippet that shows how I'm doing the cloning:

```java
for (Member member : allMembers) {
    memberName = member.getFirstName();
    // `schedule` below is a WorkBook object
    XSSFSheet individualSheet = schedule.cloneSheet(0, memberName);

    highlightMemberNames(individualSheet, memberName);
}
```

What `highlightMemberNames(individualSheet, memberName)` is doing is highlighting the cells in `individualSheet` that contain `memberName`. Here's it's code:

```java
void highlightMemberNames(XSSFSheet individualSheet, String memberName) {
    for (Row row : individualSheet) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            if (cell.getStringCellValue().equals(memberName)) {
                cell.getCellStyle().setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_GREEN.index);
                cell.getCellStyle().setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_GREEN.index);
                cell.getCellStyle().setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                cell.getCellStyle().setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Excel` files cell styles are on workbook level and not on worksheet level or on cell level. So your `cell.getCellStyle()` gets a cell style from workbook level which also may be applied to other cells in other worksheets already. If you then change that style this changes all cells in all worksheets which have that cell style applied.

You need creating all needed cell styles on workbook level first and then applying those styles to cells or you need using `CellUtil` methods. Using `CellUtil` methods should be the preferred approach.

[CellUtil](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html) methods are made for setting single cell style properties to single cells. The methods then internally decide whether new cell styles needs to be created on workbook level or whether there are such styles already which only needs to be applied.

In your case this could look like:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
```

...

```
 void highlightMemberNames(Sheet individualSheet, String memberName) {
  Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  properties.put(CellUtil.FILL_PATTERN, FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
  properties.put(CellUtil.FILL_FOREGROUND_COLOR, IndexedColors.LIGHT_GREEN.getIndex());
  properties.put(CellUtil.ALIGNMENT, HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
  for (Row row : individualSheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING && cell.getStringCellValue().equals(memberName)) {
     CellUtil.setCellStyleProperties(cell, properties); 
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: The highlighting problem is fixed. Thanks! But now the horizontal alignment of the cells that don't even match the condition `if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING && cell.getStringCellValue().equals(memberName))` is changing from `HorizontalAlignment.CENTER` to `HorizontalAlignment.LEFT` on some of the cloned sheets (I notice an unpredictable pattern).

Comment: @Mike: I cannot reproducing your alignment issue. If you needs help further ask a new question about this providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and a sample "master" sheet where the problem occurs.